# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate - not updating selection

Tags: express, mongoose, mern

I'm following a tutorial with MERN (source code here: https://github.com/Nikhilthadani/Book-Store-With-MERN-Stack/blob/Backend/controllers/books-controller.js)

Everything seems fine with the initial routing (get & post) , until we added a route for updating entries (PUT) in mongoDB.

Here is my function for the PUT

```
//book-controller.js

const updateBook = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const { name, code } = req.body;
    let book;
    try {
      book = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {new: true}, {
        name,
        code,
      });
      book = await book.save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (!book) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Unable To Update By this ID" });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ book });
  };
```

Here is my Schema

```
// Book.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    code: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);
```

When I try to test this function in Postman, the GET request returns the entry that I'm attempting to update just fine.

Confirming database entry with Get:

[image: Confirming database entry with Get]

However after testing PUT the particular entry I'm trying to update will remain unchanged, despite no output errors.

Testing PUT with Postman:

[image: Testing PUT with Postman]

Comment: you put the update document in wrong order, it should be (query, update, option)

Comment: ```book = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {name,code}, {new: true});``` Honestly I'm at a loss of what else to fix. Is there something else I'm missing? Because other requests like GET and POST are working fine

Answer (score 0):

if you read the mongoose doc, then you will find the following order of parameters:
findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {new: true});

**Also**:
when you send the data you insert additional layer which is **book**, instead
send the following:
**{
"name:"aaaaa",
"code":52
}**
or you can keep it. but in the server side, instead of req.body, write **req.body.book**